# ARM NEON: load data from addresses contained in NEON registers (Q / D registers)

Tags: arm, memory-address, neon

I'm working on a assembly ARM NEON code that consists of two parts. The first part calculates various addresses (memory) starting from a base address added to some computed values (the results are very distant memory addresses). The second part has to load data from the addresses computed in the first part and use them. Both the first and the second part are highly parallelizable and use only NEON parallelism.

What I need is to find the best way to combine the two parts: load data using the addresses output from the first phase.

What I've tried and seems to work is the simplest solution:

```
//q8 & q9 have 8 computed addresses
VMOV.32 r0, d16[0] //move addresses to standard registers
VMOV.32 r1, d16[1]
VMOV.32 r2, d17[0]
VMOV.32 r3, d17[1]
VLD1.8 d28[0], [r0] //load uchar (deinterleaving in d28 and d29)
VLD1.8 d29[0], [r1] //otherwise do not interleave and use VUZP
VLD1.8 d28[1], [r2]
VLD1.8 d29[1], [r3]
VMOV.32 r0, d18[0]
VMOV.32 r1, d18[1]
VMOV.32 r2, d19[0]
VMOV.32 r3, d19[1]
VLD1.8 d28[2], [r0]
VLD1.8 d29[2], [r1]
VLD1.8 d28[3], [r2]
VLD1.8 d29[3], [r3]
...
//data loaded in d28 and d29
```

In this example I've used four R registers (can use less or more), and I'm de-interleaving data in d28 and d29 simulating a standard VLD2.8 working on an array.

As this problem (compute addresses in NEON and load from those addresses) happens to me often, is there a better way?
Thanks

Comment: What is the algorithm to calculate load address?  May be you can use v6 simd instructions?

Answer (score 1):

What you did might work, but you shouldn't do that.

While ARM->NEON transfers are nimble, NEON->ARM transfers aren't. They cause pipeline stalls wasting about 14 cycles each time initiated.

In your case, 28 cycles are wasted for nothing. And I'm sure doing the math with ARM would take much less.

Stick to ARM. When dealing with multiple 32bit data like addresses, ARMv7 heavily benefits from its dual(triple) issuing capability. (except for multiplications)